# How to upload document to SharePoint document library using PowerAPP Custom Form?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, flow, powerapp

I am facing issue while uploading document from local machine to SharePoint document library using power App Custom form. I am not able to convert file content to binary using flow.
I am using flow to upload document from power App Custom form to SharePoint Document library.